# Using XML column in a where clause in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, xml-column

I have a stored procedure in which I need to have a where clause that reads something like:

```
where XMLDataPoint <> NULL
```

However, XMLDataPoint is an XML column and I get an error

> "The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the
>   IS NULL operator."

How should I structure my where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` requires using `IS` or `IS NOT` comparisons:

`WHERE XMLDataPoint IS NOT NULL`

`NULL` is a **state** (of having an unknown or undetermined value), **not a value** itself, so equivalence operators don't apply.